# Mysterious Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParseException

Tags: windows-8, visual-studio-2012, windows-runtime

I'm trying to develop some custom controls (I'm actually using **Templated Control** to do this if that matters) for a windows app store app.  I'm getting a rather ambiguous error (as seen in the title).  The only additional information is this:

```
WinRT information: Cannot create instance of type 'SoundControls.tcNote' [Line: 13 Position: 51]
```

I'm not sure if the issue is with the Generic.xaml file where the layout of the control is defined (as I would think the error seems to point to) or the code behind file.

Either way, here is line 13 for both:

*Generic.xaml*

```
BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
```

*Code Behind*

```
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
```

Both seem rather meaningless and innocuous.  Does anyone have ideas on what to look at closer to solve this error? I am willing to post code snippets and such (as relevant/requested) but I always hate looking at a question and seeing nothing but pages of code.

**EDIT:**

Constructor as requested:

```
this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(tcNote);

(GetTemplateChild("PART_note") as Thumb).DragStarted += tcNote_DragStarted;
(GetTemplateChild("PART_note") as Thumb).DragDelta += tcNote_DragDelta;
(GetTemplateChild("PART_note") as Thumb).DragCompleted += tcNote_DragCompleted;
```

**Second Edit/Solution:**

I figured out that the line 13 issue is in MainPage.xaml.

```
<SoundControls:tcNote HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
```

That line looks like it has an error on it (the blue underline, but it still let me build) and if I hover over it it says "Delegate to an instance method cannot have null 'this'."  The issue seems to be that *PART_note* wasn't available yet.  I needed to move those lines in the constructor into the **OnApplyTemplate** method.

Comment: What code is at Line 13, Position 51?  What does the constructor for 'SoundControls.tcNote' look like?

Comment: Please, never edit the question to add the answer to it. That is not where others can vote for it or will look for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you maybe instantiating `SoundControls.tcNote` in some other XAML file at line 13? The error could originate from there.

The problem might be either:

- in your control's constructor: Are you sure `GetTemplateChild("PART_note") as Thumb` isn't null? Does it help if you comment out These lines?
- or somewhere in its XAML: parse error because of unresolvable `StaticResource` referencesor of some other error.

I would start troubleshooting the issue by minimizing the amount of code / XAML in the control and seeing if the problem goes away.

Comment: I commented those out in the constructor and that let it run.  As noted in my question now I needed to move those to the OnApplyTemplate method.

Answer (score 1):

When I encounter this error I do two things:

1. Check the InnerException (repeat this step until it is *null*) to get a better idea of what is going on. Fix it.
2. If there is no InnerException (or it is too vague) I comment out all XAML and start slowly bringing it back. This helps to pinpoint the offending XAML or code.

Comment: Unfortunately there are no inner exceptions for me to check.

Comment: If there is no InnerException it probably is not the XAML. The XAML parser nearly always gives innerexceptions. And yes you are correct It is only just before the `OnApplyTemplate` that the control and its inner controls are built up. So you are correct that to move the GetTemplateChild code to that method.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old question. I just stumble into this error, in my case it was because in one language resource i was setting the Text of a Textbox that was also bound to a property in the view model. Of course, there was no clue about this in the exception, the inner exception was closed, and it only showed on the emulator, since the local machine was using another culture. This made it difficult to track down. Maybe this will help some unfortunate soul.